# Pandas - check if dataframe has negative value in any column

Tags: python, pandas

I wonder how to check if a pandas dataframe has negative value in 1 or more columns and
return only boolean value (True or False). Can you please help?

```
In[1]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 3))

In[2]: df
Out[2]:
          0         1         2
0 -1.783811  0.736010  0.865427
1 -1.243160  0.255592  1.670268
2  0.820835  0.246249  0.288464
3 -0.923907 -0.199402  0.090250
4 -1.575614 -1.141441  0.689282
5 -1.051722  0.513397  1.471071
6  2.549089  0.977407  0.686614
7 -1.417064  0.181957  0.351824
8  0.643760  0.867286  1.166715
9 -0.316672 -0.647559  1.331545
```

Expected output:-

```
Out[3]: True
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually, if speed is important, I did a few tests:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10000, 30000))
```

Test 1, slowest: pure pandas

```
(df < 0).any().any()
# 303 ms ± 1.28 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Test 2, faster: switching over to numpy with `.values` for testing the presence of a `True` entry

```
(df < 0).values.any()
# 269 ms ± 8.19 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Test 3, maybe even faster, though not significant: switching over to numpy for the whole thing

```
(df.values < 0).any()
# 267 ms ± 1.48 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can chain two `any`

```
df.lt(0).any().any()
Out[96]: True
```

Answer (score 4):

This does the trick:

```
(df < 0).any().any()
```

To break it down, `(df < 0)` gives a dataframe with boolean entries. Then the first `.any()` returns a series of booleans, testing within each column for the presence of a `True` value. And then, the second `.any()` asks whether this returned series itself contains any `True` value.

This returns a simple:

```
True
```

Comment: df.lt(0).any().any() from YOBEN_S seems to be faster. Thanks Billjoie, i like your explanation though

Comment: No problem. I see no difference in speed though. With a df of shape 1000 x 300, my answer gives 325 µs ± 9.38 µs per loop, compared to 326 µs ± 3.84 µs per loop, over 7 loops on my machine.